# Redux-observable combineepics not mapping

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs

I am new to redux-observables and I am attempting to combine epics, however it is not working as I believe it should. The below code makes "MENU_TOGGLE" toggle correctly and delay prior to console logging out that a button has been pressed, but the LOGIN_REQUEST won't mapTo LOGIN_SUCCESS. I have the following example:

```
import { combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import 'rxjs';

const loginRequest = action$ =>
    action$.ofType('LOGIN_REQUEST')
      .delay(1000)
      .mapTo({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' });

const menuToggle = action$ =>
    action$.ofType('MENU_TOGGLE')
      .delay(1000)
      .subscribe(action => {
          console.log('Button pressed!');
      });

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(
    loginRequest, menuToggle
);
```

The above is just an example, I have the actual code in separate files, however even this does not seem to work. If I alter it to:

```
export const rootEpic = combineEpics(loginRequest);
```

then it fires correctly. As soon as I add an additional epic to combineEpics, it won't fire the epic any longer.

I cannot seem to figure out where I might be making a mistake. Any assistance is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Does it works when you combine only `menuToggle` ?

Comment: Yes, menuToggle works regardless. It's when I add an epic that applies a mapTo. If I took the subscribe away from menuToggle and added a mapTo another action, it does the same thing. Both epics work independently if I remove one from the combineEpics function, however when both are there the one with a mapTo refuses to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `menuToggle` epic is using `subscribe`, and `subscribe` finalize the action stream, make other epics not being able to listen on the stream anymore. So, instead of using `subscribe`, use something like this:

```
const menuToggle = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('MENU_TOGGLE')
    .delay(1000)
    .do(action => {
      console.log('Button pressed!');
    })
    .ignoreElements();
```

You may read this [issue](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/169) to know more about how to handle epic that doesn't return an action.

Comment: That corrected it! Thank you so much! I didn't realize it ended the stream. I am an Angular Dev and am coming over to React, so a lot of learning curve here.

Comment: Good luck! While React's learning curve is relatively steep, when you understood it, there should be no problem learning any other web framework later on.